# User loads temp profile every login

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2003

I have a pc where only 1 domain user keeps getting a temp profile each time that user logs in. I tried logging with a different user on the same pc and the profile loaded just fine.

It is a Server 2003 Domain and the pc is running Windows 7 Pro. Is the user profile corrupt on the domain? if so, what should I do to fix it?

There is no user folder on the PC anymore.

Comment: If the user logs into a different computer and it works, then it's just the local profile on that single machine. Delete it and it will be created anew the next time they try to log in.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like typical user profile corruption. The easiest way to fix it in my opinion is to delete the user from active directory and move or delete their user profile from the profile share. After this recreate the user account, log in to create a new profile, then you can restore files from the old profile if you moved it.